# HTML5 video doesn't play in Safari with different shared hosting

Tags: html, apache, html5-video

I tried to include HTML5 video tag in my landing page of website in http://sprnv.sg and http://creazidigital.com/supernova with the same code. I checked it and it plays well in browsers I tested (Chrome, Firefox).

I also check it (http://creazidigital.com/supernova) on Safari Browser which is played well.But I am shocked that the website on http://sprnv.sg doesn't play the video with Safari browser.

This is the demo video of the websites https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ua2gsek1c788p8/SPRNV%20problem.mov?dl=0

I also contact the administrator of http://sprnv.sg, and they said they have included MIME type of Web Server they using.

Thank you, and Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the gzip compression on mp4 files.

This is how the mp4 file is delivered on creazdigital.com:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 May 2017 03:19:34 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 524072-524072/591649
Content-Length: 1
Date: Wed, 10 May 2017 06:13:28 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

This is how it is delivered on sprnv.sg:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 03:10:41 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: video/mp4
Server: - Web acceleration by http://www.unixy.net/varnish
X-Cacheable: YES
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 10 May 2017 06:12:51 GMT
X-Varnish: 839343921 839343905
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent, User-Agent
age: 0
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 2
Content-Range: bytes 495206-495206/581865
Content-Length: 1
```

Maybe this is a side effect of Varnish, but it's safe to check both Apache and Varnish configs.

For some reason, Chrome and Firefox are not affected, even tho the webm files are gzipped too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. This is solving by excluding from Varnish (They said)..